# What are the best free Scheme implementations that you know about on Windows?

Tags: windows, scheme, racket

When I wrote best I meant:

- Speed,
- Have an IDE, a debugger,
- Compiling to machine code or some other language,
- Quality of implementation and,
- Completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, I recommend [PLT Scheme](http://plt-scheme.org/) which includes the DrScheme programming environment.

Comment: It looks nice but I have a problem with the current version. The generated executable exits with an error when it is run.

Comment: @Aftershock, I have DrScheme v4.1 (old version) installed in my computer. Simple console programs (`#lang scheme`) run fine. Are you sure there isn't a bug in your code?

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure because the code runs when interpreted. The code is also compiled with gambie. I have tried more than one code.

Comment: Weird. If you compile a simple `(display "hello")`, do you still get the same error? BTW, I run it on Windows XP. I can check out the latest DrScheme version on Windows 7 tomorrow. If you want post a sample to test it.

Comment: It looks like a minor problem to fix. I guess it will disappear in the next version. It shows that they do not use a test suite for gui.